# Referenciar OPTION em javascript

Tags: html, funções, select, option

Seguinte: Tenho que inserir os dados de nome e preço e estado, dependendo do estado ele calcula o icms. Eu queria fazer com que dependendo da OPTION que eu selecionar ele calculasse automaticamente, com os if's e else's. mas nao sei se estou referenciando certo a id do option para o javascript. Podem me ajudar? É um pouco urgente

Calculo ICMS

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var nome;
    var preco;
    var estado;
    var icms=0;

    function calculo(){
        nome = document.calculo.nome.value;
        preco = parseFloat(document.calculo.preco.value);
        estado = document.getElementById("estado").id;

        if (estado.id="sp") {
            icms = preco * 0.019;
        }else{
            if (estado.id="rj") {
                icms = preco * 0.012;
            }else{
                if (estado.id="sc") {
                    icms = preco * 0.09;
                }else{
                    if (estado.id="se") {
                        icms = preco * 0.08;
                    }else{
                        if (estado.id="mg") {
                            icms = preco * 0.1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        alert('ICMS: ' + icms.toString());

    }
</script>
```

```
<form name="calculo">
    <label for="nome" title="Nome do produto">Digite o nome do produto</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="nome">

    <br><br>

    <label for="preco" title="Preço">Digite o preço do produto</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="preco">

    <br><br>

    <label>Estado</label>
    <select id="estado">
        <option id="sp"> SP
        <option id="mg"> MG
        <option id="rj"> RJ
        <option id="sc"> SC
        <option id="se"> SE 
    </select>


    <br><br>

    <input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calculo()">
    <input type="reset" value="Limpar">

</form>
```

Comment: Os ifs estão todos errados. Tem que usar `==` para comparar valores, e não apenas um `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O operador de comparação são dois `==` e não um. Apenas um `=` é sinal de atribuição (atribuir um valor a alguma coisa).

Para pegar o atributo do option selecionado você pode usar `elemento_select.selectedIndex`. Ao usar `document.getElementById("estado").id;` você está pegando o `id` do select e não do option.

Não precisa aninhar os `if`'s desta forma, use `else if`. Crie mais uma variável `uf` para selecionar o elemento `select` e a variável `estado` com o `id` do option selecionado.

Outro problema também é que você deu o nome do formulário com o mesmo nome da função (`calculo`). Com isso o objeto `calculo` será o formulário e não a função, o que retornará em erro quando você chama a função `calculo()` no onclick. Tem que trocar uma coisa ou outra com nomes diferentes. No caso abaixo eu troquei o nome do form para `calculos`:

```js
var nome;
var preco;
var estado;
var icms=0;
var uf;

function calculo(){
  nome = document.calculos.nome.value;
  preco = parseFloat(document.calculos.preco.value);
  uf = document.getElementById("estado");
  estado = uf.options[uf.selectedIndex].id;

  if (estado=="sp") {
      icms = preco * 0.019;
  }else if(estado=="rj") {
      icms = preco * 0.012;
  }else if (estado="sc") {
      icms = preco * 0.09;
  }else if (estado=="se") {
      icms = preco * 0.08;
  }else if (estado=="mg") {
      icms = preco * 0.1;
  }

  alert('ICMS: ' + icms.toString());

}
```

```html
<form name="calculos">
    <label for="nome" title="Nome do produto">Digite o nome do produto</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="nome">

    <br><br>

    <label for="preco" title="Preço">Digite o preço do produto</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="preco">

    <br><br>

    <label>Estado</label>
    <select id="estado">
        <option id="sp"> SP</option>
        <option id="mg"> MG</option>
        <option id="rj"> RJ</option>
        <option id="sc"> SC</option>
        <option id="se"> SE </option>
    </select>


    <br><br>

    <input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calculo()">
    <input type="reset" value="Limpar">

</form>
```

Comment: Valeu mano, deu certo. Mt obrigado!!

Comment: Legal! Se puder marcar ✔ na resposta. Valeu!